# React - Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

[[enter image description here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiSHd.png)

Hello, I'm a new developer who has been working as a frontend developer for less than a year.

I'm making a blog project to study react.

However, the following error occurred in the middle.

I've been trying for a long time to figure this out, but I just couldn't find the answer.

There are many other files, but the error file code that I think is most likely is as follows.

I would really appreciate your help.

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import {
 POST_DETAIL_LOADING_REQUEST,
 POST_DELETE_REQUEST,
 USER_LOADING_REQUEST,
 POST_DETAIL_LOADING_SUCCESS,
 POST_DETAIL_LOADING_FAILURE,
} from "../../redux/types";
import { Button, Row, Col, Container } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import GrowingSpinner from "../../components/spinner/Spinner";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
 faPencilAlt,
 faCommentDots,
 faMouse,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import BalloonEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor";
import { editorConfiguration } from "../../components/editor/EditorConfig";
import Comments from "../../components/comments/Comments";


const PostDetail = (req) => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const { postDetail, creatorId, title, loading } = useSelector(
   (state) => state.post
 );
 const { userId, userName } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
 const { comments } = useSelector((state) => state.comment);

 console.log(req);
 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch({
     type: POST_DETAIL_LOADING_REQUEST,
     payload: req.match.params.id,
   });
   dispatch({
     type: USER_LOADING_REQUEST,
     payload: localStorage.getItem("token"),
   });
 }, [dispatch, req.match.params.id]);

 const onDeleteClick = () => {
   dispatch({
     type: POST_DELETE_REQUEST,
     payload: {
       id: req.match.params.id,
       token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
     },
   });
 };

 const EditButton = (
   <Fragment>
     <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center pb-3">
       <Col className="col-md-3 mr-md-3">
         <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
           Home
         </Link>
       </Col>
       <Col className="col-md-3 mr-md-3">
         <Link
           to={`/post/${req.match.params.id}/edit`}
           className="btn btn-success btn-block"
         >
           Edit Post
         </Link>
       </Col>
       <Col className="col-md-3">
         <Button className="btn-block btn-danger" onClick={onDeleteClick}>
           Delete
         </Button>
       </Col>
     </Row>
   </Fragment>
 );

 const HomeButton = (
   <Fragment>
     <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center pb-3">
       <Col className="col-sm-12 com-md-3">
         <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
           Home
         </Link>
       </Col>
     </Row>
   </Fragment>
 );

 const Body = (
   <>
     {userId === creatorId ? EditButton : HomeButton}
     <Row className="border-bottom border-top border-primary p-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
       {(() => {
         if (postDetail && postDetail.creator) {
           return (
             <Fragment>
               <div className="font-weight-bold text-big">
                 <span className="mr-3">
                   <Button color="info">
                     {postDetail.category.categoryName}
                   </Button>
                 </span>
                 {postDetail.title}
               </div>
               <div className="align-self-end">{postDetail.creator.name}</div>
             </Fragment>
           );
         }
       })()}
     </Row>
     {postDetail && postDetail.comments ? (
       <Fragment>
         <div className="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-baseline small">
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} />
           &nbsp;
           <span> {postDetail.date}</span>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCommentDots} />
           &nbsp;
           <span>{postDetail.comments.length}</span>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMouse} />
           <span>{postDetail.views}</span>
         </div>
         <Row className="mb-3">
           <CKEditor
             editor={BalloonEditor}
             data={postDetail.contents}
             config={editorConfiguration}
             disabled="true"
           />
         </Row>
         <Row>
           <Container className="mb-3 border border-blue rounded">
             {Array.isArray(comments)
               ? comments.map(
                   ({ contents, creator, date, _id, creatorName }) => (
                     <div key={_id}>
                       <Row className="justify-content-between p-2">
                         <div className="font-weight-bold">
                           {creatorName ? creatorName : creator}
                         </div>
                         <div className="text-small">
                           <span className="font-weight-bold">
                             {date.split[0]}
                           </span>
                           <span className="font-weight-light">
                  
                             {date.split[1]}
                           </span>
                         </div>
                       </Row>
                       <Row className="p-2">
                         <div>{contents}</div>
                       </Row>
                       <hr />
                     </div>
                   )
                 )
               : "Creator"}
             <Comments
               id={req.match.params.id}
               userId={userId}
               userName={userName}
             />
           </Container>
         </Row>
       </Fragment>
     ) : (
       <h1>hi</h1>
     )}
   </>
 );

 console.log(comments, "Comments");
 return (
   <div>
     <Helmet title={`Post | ${title}`} />
     {loading === true ? GrowingSpinner : Body}
   </div>
 );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

<Helmet title={`Post | ${title}`} />

Even though you wrote the syntax above, the title value is not output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTuAP.png)

The structure is as follows:

(postWrite) -> write post + click button -> *save post + move postDetail page (error)*

+) The code is quite long, but I'm sorry I couldn't highlight it. As for me, I have no idea which part of this file is the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through the code and the error message you're seeing, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the exported component. Rather, it seems that the way you're importing the component might be wrong.

```
export default PostDetail
```

This means that you'll need to import the component using this syntax:

```
import PostDetail from './path-to-component'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I still haven't solved this error. We solved the problem where the title does not appear by replacing the <React.Fragment> with <div> tags. (But we don't understand the principle.) Let's continue to find a way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem, mine was fixed when I used

```js
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
```

in place of

```js
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
```